# Is it possible to access the value associated with the "-c" parameter from a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, arguments

I would like to do `bash -c '<some smart bash script>'` that would output the actual string passed to -c.

In other words, if `SCRIPT` is set to that smart script, `bash -c "$SCRIPT"` should yield what's in `$SCRIPT`.

Is that possible? If yes, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [`man bash`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Variables)

> **5.2 Bash Variables**
>   ...
>   BASH_EXECUTION_STRING
>       The command argument to the -c invocation option.

If you try

```
bash -c 'echo $BASH_EXECUTION_STRING'
```

it will give you

> echo $BASH_EXECUTION_STRING